# How to use two different encoders (CNN model) in In adda implementation from apat package?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, github-api, transfer-learning

I could not find the way to use two different encoders  i.e one for Source and another one for Target.

in my application for ADDA I need to use TWO different CNN network. but could not find the way out in apat package
https://adapt-python.github.io/adapt/generated/adapt.feature_based.ADDA.html

classadapt.feature_based.ADDA(encoder=None, task=None, discriminator=None, Xt=None, pretrain=True, tol=0.001, copy=True, verbose=1, random_state=None, **params)

Can anyone help me, how to use two different encoders i.e source and target encoders